# Is it an acceptable structure to nest Navigator components?

Tags: react-native

I have a mobile app where the flow is basically this:

1. User loads app, is presented with a login/OAuth screen
2. There are other scenes in the stack that could be pushed on top of this (sign up, forgot password, etc) - related scenes
3. No TabBarIOS at this point

Once the user authenticates, they're taken to a totally different screen that has a TabBarIOS at the bottom to switch between (for example) messages, settings, news, etc. If on the news tab (listing of news item) and the user taps a news item to view the article, the detail view is pushed onto the stack but the TabBarIOS remains visible.

So I have one main Navigator at the root level to swap between the login/signup stack, and the "user is logged in" stack, and then I have another Navigator within that so the user can navigate around in the news articles.

I'm just wondering if this is a bad pattern in React Native and if there's a better way, or if this is spot on.

Comment: I don't think this is a bad pattern, and I am not aware of any other way to implement what you are talking about than with multiple navigators. We're doing basically the same thing in production with no worries or issues to speak of.

Comment: I also think that this is the right way to do this. Furthermore, it is easier to maintain application structure.